# json_encode returns invalid json format (for me)

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
    $a = 'aa,ss';
    $b = explode(',', $a);
    $c = json_encode($b);
    echo $c;
```

This code is returning:

```
["aa","ss"]
```

I need:

```
{"0":"aa","1":"ss"}
```

Comment: `So it is not a valid JSON code` - says who? Seems valid to me.

Comment: `["aa","ss"]` is valid JSON

Comment: If you need an object, check out the FORCE_OBJECT parameter http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. But acctually I need it to be: {0: "aa",1:"ss"} or something simmilar

Comment: Thank you Pekka, please write an answer and I will give you rep

Comment: @Davgranded I don't think Pekka feels such an urge for rep points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON has two **equally valid** styles of formatting:

- **Objects**
- **Arrays**

What you have is an array. What you seem to think as "valid" is an object.

To output an object with PHP's `json_encode()`, you can do like this:

```
json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

And you will have what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use **JSON_FORCE_OBJECT** at json_encode. Non-associative array output as object:

```
$a = 'aa,ss';
$b = explode(',', $a);
$c = json_encode($b, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $c;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 'aa,ss';
$b = explode(',', $a);

$object = new stdClass();
foreach ($b as $key => $value)
{
    $object->$key = $value;
}
$c = json_encode($object);
echo $c;
```

that will output what you want

Comment: thanks :) but i have already chosen version with JSON_FORCE_OBJECT